# Compute the projective dimension of the given $R$-module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

> Let
>   $$R=\frac{K[[x,y,z]]}{\left<xz,yz\right>}\text{ and } M=\frac{R}{\left<z+\left<xz,yz\right>\right>}.$$
>   Compute the projective dimension of $M$ as an $R$-module.

My attempt to arrive at a solution:

I haven't completely solved the problem and I'm not really sure, but I think Auslander-Buchsbaum formula can be applied to this problem to compute projective dimension:

$R$ is isomorphic to $K[[x,y]]\oplus K[[z]]$ and $M$ as an $R$-module is isomorphic to $K[[x,y]]$.

$R$ is Noetherian, because both $K[[x,y]]$ and $K[[z]]$ are Noetherian. R is local with the maximal ideal $m=<x,y> \oplus <z>$. It is maximal because the quotient is a field and it is the unique maximal because $x,y$ and $z$ being non-units must lie in maximal ideals and I guess this will tell us something about why $m$ is maximal.

Now $\rm{depth_R(M)}=2$ because x,y is a $M$-regular sequence in $m$
$\rm{depth(R)}=3$ because z,x,y is a $R$-regular sequence in $m$

Therefore, by Auslander-Buchsbaum formula $$\rm{pd_R(M)}+\rm{depth_R(M)}=\rm{depth(R)}$$

which gives $\rm{pd_R(M)}=1$.

$\rm{pd_R(M)}<\infty$ because of Hilbert's syzygy theorem or something.

Sorry for being intuitive and non-rigorous. I shared my attempt only to show that I have given the problem some thought.

Comment: Having done your intuitive work, now try to be rigorous. First, are you sure $R$ is isomorphic to the direct sum you write down? Also, Hilbert's syzygy or something is a bit too much. Please read the theorem and see whether it applies.

Comment: A direct product $A\times B$ of rings is *rarely* a local ring, @user246836...

Comment: $R$ is not regular (not even CM), so you have no reason to think that $M$ has finite projective dimension. However, if you assume it is, then get immediately a contradiction (from A-B formula), so pd M is infinite.

Comment: :( This was an exam problem. I naively ruled out $\rm{pd_R(M)=\infty}$. Now the exam's over, I'm going to give it some thought how to get a contradiction from A-B formula. @user26857

Comment: @Mohan: Well, I was trying to rewrite things down more rigorously until user246836 proved me wrong. I didn't have enough time in the exam to write things down rigorously and I didn't know the statement for Hilbert's syzygy theorem. So, I just tried my luck. I'm sorry for the wrong proof, but I think it's actually a good problem for learning to actually compute things rather than just learning only the theory.

Comment: You were told that $R$ is not Cohen-Macaulay. Even if you are not willing to verify this, this should give you an idea what the depth of $R$ will be. It will be strictly smaller than the dimension (which should be easy to figure out).

Comment: @Moos Do you mean we get $\rm{pd_R(M)}<0$ (which is a contradiction since $M$ is non-zero) assuming that the rest of my proof is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should complete the following steps:

- $x+z$ is regular on $R$.
- $R/(x+z)$ has depth $0$.
- Deduce that $R$ has depth $1$.

Since you have computed the depth of $M$ to be $2$, Auslander-Buchsbaum cannot hold, i.e. the projective dimension of $M$ cannot be finite.